# BPMN 2.0 Revert to previous task from anywhere in workflow

Tags: bpmn

Is there some special notation in BPMN to indicate that a task to should return to the previous task.  I can do that with a XOR gate and lots of paths out depending on the entered state, but seems a bit unwieldly.  Say you have a large workflow which contains the notion of a company, and at any point that company can go on sanctions, suspending the workflow, i.e.:
[image]

But as the number of tasks goes up this becomes cumbersome:

[image]

It can be made slightly better if the "Wait for sanctions lift" task knows where it came from:

[image]

But it is still kind of ugly.